# Difficulty in understanding the proof for convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand the proof for  convergence of an algorithm.

Here is the proof. Assuming:

A is a Symmetric positive definite matrix

$x_{k+1} = x_k + αr_k + \beta Ar_k$

$ r_{k+1} =r_k −A(\alpha r_k + \beta Ar_k) \quad \quad  r_{k+1}\perp  Ar_k \text{ and } r_{k+1} \perp r_k$

$ \quad \quad \text{where }  r_i\in \mathbb{R^n} , A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, \text{ and } \alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R} $

Thus, we have:

$\begin{cases} (r_k −\alpha Ar_k −βA^2r_k,r_k)=0 \\
(r_k −\alpha Ar_k −\beta A^2r_k,Ar_k)=0 \end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}(r_k, r_k) = \alpha(Ar_k, r_k) + \beta(A^2r_k, r_k) \\
(r_k, Ar_k) = \alpha(Ar_k, Ar_k) + \beta(A^2r_k, Ar_k)\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}(r_k, r_k) = \alpha(Ar_k, r_k) + β(A^2r_k, r_k) \\
 (Ar_k, r_k) = \alpha (A^2r_k, r_k) + \beta(A^3r_k, r_k) \end{cases}$

We also know  $r_{k} = Ad_{k}$ and $r_{k+1} = Ad_{k+1}$

$\|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2}= (Ad_{k+1}, d_{k+1})$

$= (r_{k+1}, d_{k+1})$

$=(r_{k+1}, d_k − \alpha r_k − \beta Ar_k)$

$=(r_{k+1},d_k)$

$=(r_k −\alpha Ar_k −\beta A^{2}r_k,d_k)$

$= (r_k, d_k) − \alpha(r_k, Ad_k) − \beta(A^2r_k, d_k)$

$= (Ad_k, d_k) − \alpha(r_k, r_k) − \beta(Ar_k, r_k)$

$ = \|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2} − \alpha \|r_k\| − \beta \|r_k\|_A$

$\rightarrow \|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2} ≤ \|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2}$

I don't understand how the last line ($ \|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2} = \|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2} − \alpha \|r_k\| − \beta \|r_k\|_A \rightarrow \|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2} ≤ \|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2}$) was concluded?

I would appreciate any help to understand this. 
Thank you.

PS: I don't know if value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ needed since it was not mentioned in the proof. But It can be obtain as follows:

$\begin{bmatrix} r_k& Ar_k \end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta  \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} r_k&Ar_k \end{bmatrix}(\begin{bmatrix} r_k&Ar_k \end{bmatrix}^TA\begin{bmatrix} r_k&Ar_k\end{bmatrix})^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} r_k&Ar_k\end{bmatrix}^{T}r_k$

$ \quad \quad \text{where }  r_k\in \mathbb{R^n} , A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, \text{ and } \alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R} $

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the last line (it should be $\|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2}$ not $\|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2}$):

\begin{equation}
\|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2}= (Ad_{k+1}, d_{k+1})
= (Ad_k, d_k) − \alpha(r_k, r_k) − \beta(Ar_k, r_k)\\
\|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2} = \|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2} − \alpha \|r_k\| − \beta \|r_k\|_A \rightarrow \|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2} ≤ \|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2}
\end{equation}

If $\alpha,\beta\ge 0$ we have a positive quantity ($\|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2}$) less two negative numbers ($− \alpha \|r_k\| − \beta \|r_k\|_A$) so you get $\|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2}$ subtracting $− \alpha \|r_k\| − \beta \|r_k\|_A$ by $\|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2}$...hence $\|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2} ≤ \|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2}$.

Comment: Thank you Matt. Sorry for the typo, I will fix it. If it is possible would you please explain why($ \|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2} = \|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2} − \alpha \|r_k\| − \beta \|r_k\|_A \rightarrow \|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2} ≤ \|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2}$) ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understood what you wrote. But how could I be sure $\alpha , \beta \geq 0 $?

Comment: If $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ but they are not positive then you can't say that $\|d_{k+1}\|_{A}^{2} ≤ \|d_{k}\|_{A}^{2}$..

Comment: Since It is a proof, I guess there is some other relations between these values that guarantees the conclusion but I could not find it.

Comment: Are you sure about $\alpha,\beta$? Are $\in\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R^+}$?

Comment: They are both  $\in R$ .I tested a random case for a S.P.D matrix , called $A$ , and a non-zero $r$. The obtained $\beta$ was negative and $\alpha$ was positive. At the end of my post I added a formula for calculating $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Have you tested if the inequality was true in your test?

Comment: No. I will look at that later. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, you're welcome!!